# Как правильно вызвать и получить результат хранимой процедуры из БД MS SQL, чтобы потом обработать его в коде Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, хранимые-процедуры

Сама процедура:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Authentification](@login as nvarchar(15),@password as nvarchar(64), @Answer NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT)  

IF (Select count(*) from Users where Users.Login = @login AND Users.Password = @password) = 0     SET @Answer = 'Отсутствует в базе'  Return @Answer 

IF   (Select count(*) from Users where Users.Login = @login AND Users.Password = @password) = 1   SET @Answer = 'Присутствует в базе  Return @Answer
```

При попытке получить результат вот так:

```
        sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Users", sqlConnection);
        sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter);


        dataSet = new DataSet();

        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Users");

        SqlCommand CheckAuth = new SqlCommand("Authentification", sqlConnection);
        CheckAuth.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AuthLogin.Text;
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Verification.GetSHA256Hash(AuthPassword.Text);
        CheckAuth.Parameters.Add("@Answer", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";

        //sqlConnection.Open();
         var result = CheckAuth.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Выдаёт ошибку преобразования Nvarchar to int.

Comment: Код хранимки вставьте текстом, а не скриншотом. Добавьте метки используемых языков.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, показываю только для выходного параметра процедуры

```
var answer = new SqlParameter("@Answer", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
answer.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
CheckAuth.Parameters.Add(answer);

CheckAuth.ExecuteNonQuery();
var res = answer.Value.ToString();
```

Ну, а дальше используйте `res`.

Comment: При попытке сделать так, выдаёт, что свойство Size имеет недопустимый размер. При принудительной установке Answer.Size = 64, выдаёт ту же самую ошибку, преобразование string в int неудачно.

Comment: У вас же string возвращает, а не число! Причем тут размер и преобразование в int ? `@Answer NVARCHAR(max) OUTPUT)` строка должна вернуться. Нет? `SET @Answer = 'Отсутствует в базе'  Return @Answer `

Comment: Я то это понимаю, но не понимаю, почему процедура считает, вернуться должен Int, а не строка. Мне тоже данный феномен кажется странным.

Comment: Вы мой пример точно внимательно прочитали? `CheckAuth.ExecuteNonQuery();` никаких чисел быть не должно. Уберите `Return @Answer` из процедуры.

Comment: А чисел то и нет. И Output Nvarchar. Однако Visual Studio упорно считает, что преобразую какое-то число.

Comment: Похоже, уборка Return решила проблему. Выдаёт, что такого в базе нет, но тут уже думаю, что-то не так, с хэшированием. Большое спасибо!